# Using MSTest within a TFS 2015 Release Definition to run a webtest

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, mstest, tfs-2015, release-management

I have a *.webtest that I'm building as part of a TFS 2015 Release Definition.  I'd like to run this test as part of the release.

I believe this requires `mstest.exe` however the `mstest` command is not recognized when running within the `Command Line` component, unlike other commands like `dotnet publish`.

Do I need to include the MSTest.exe executable within my test project or is there a more "out of the box" way to go about running webtests within a TFS 2015 Release Definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run WebTests through MSBuild tool, you can call MSBuild tool through PowerShell.

1. Add PowerShell task

Code:

```
        param (    
        $tool = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe",   
         $path ,   
         $include = "*.webtest",   
         $results ,    
        $testsettings)
            $web_tests = get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Recurse -Include $include

foreach ($item in $web_tests)
     {   

     $args += "/TestContainer:$item "

    }

    & $tool $args /resultsfile:$Results /testsettings:$testsettings
```

2. Add Publish Test Results task

More information, you can refer to this article: [Running WebTests as part of a VSTS VNext Release pipeline](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2016/05/30/Running-WebTests-as-part-of-a-VSTS-VNext-Release-pipeline)

Comment: Whoops - I commented on the wrong question.  +1, Marking as accepted.  Would you mind taking a look at this one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705026/running-webtest-tests-results-in-webtest-is-not-a-valid-extension